# ASP.NET Core MVC MapRoute default

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following MapRoute definition:

```
routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

As you can see this exactly same as the official default. In the documentation there is an explanation about defaults:

> Default and optional route parameters do not need to be present in the
>   URL path for a match.

So I created a very simple additional action in the HomeController to test the behavior of defaults:

```
public String Test()
{
    return "Route found";
}
```

Now I trying to understand why this url is not working: **'/Test'**

I'm expected if I set default controller value (=Home) then the router will find the action if it was defined in the default controller.

I'm also wondering if there is any difference between this two declaration formats:

```
routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller}/{action}/{id?}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

Comment: Because the first part is the controller and you have no TestController. The optional parts must be in order, the system can't guess which part you omitted and which submitted

Comment: OMG :) Sorry, I was a noob. Write it as an answer I will accept it. Btw I think it would be nice if controller not found then try to find an action in the default controller. Maybe I should write a custom router :)